# How to link dates with merge and get relevant calculated field?

Tags: r, reshape

Lets say i have 4 customers ( ID - 1,2,3,4) 
I have data in two tables :

```
Table 1 - lists down the dates of Purchase of A( only once a year)
ID     Date of Purchase 
1       10-03-2014
2       15-05-2014  
3       13-09-2014
4       15-10-2015

Table 2 - lists down dates of purchase of B( can be multiple times )
ID     Date of Purchase 
1       10-01-2014
1       15-05-2014  
1       15-10-2014
2       13-06-2014
2       15-10-2015
3       23-11-2014 
4       22-09-2016
```

What i need is a table giving :

Difference in dates(purchase of A from Purchase of B) for a customer with condition

1. The purchase date of B should be > then Purchase date of A
2. The difference in date should be with first purchase of B ( made after purchase of A )

Example for ID 1 -
1. Purchase of A was in 3rd month . And first purchase of B after 3rd month is in 5th month so difference is 2 months ( or equivalent days )

Example for ID 2 - Purchase of A was in 5th month , first purchase of B is in 6th month , so difference is 1 month ( or equivalent days )

```
Table3 
ID   Difference days 
1      60
2      30
```

How do i get that in R ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this approach:

```
tab1 <- data.frame(ID= c(1,2,3,4),  Date_of_Purchase = as.Date( c("10-03-2014","15-05-2014","13-09-2014","15-10-2015"), format = "%d-%m-%Y"))
tab2 <- data.frame(ID= c(1,1,1,2,2,3,4),  Date_of_Purchase = as.Date( c("10-01-2014","15-05-2014 ","15-10-2014","13-06-2014","15-05-2014 ","15-10-2014","13-06-2014"), format = "%d-%m-%Y"))
library("dplyr")    
tab <- tab1 %>% left_join(tab2, c("ID" = "ID"))
tab$dif <- tab$Date_of_Purchase.y- tab$Date_of_Purchase.x
```

then group by id and select the min

```
tab <- filter(tab, dif > 0)
tab3 <-   tab %>%
  dplyr::group_by(ID) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(min = min(dif))
```

Results:

```
     ID      min
  <dbl>   <time>
1     1  66 days
2     2  29 days
3     3  71 days
4     4 343 days
```